# How can I make flex columns containing a list and an image the same width?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

In CSS Flexbox I want to set equal width columns, when in 1st column there's list text and in second column there's a big image.
That's all. Flexbox with only 2 columns.

The problem is, that in most tutorials the example is 3 or 4 columns within a Flexbox container, and there is a different amount of text in this columns. So initially these columns are different width, because of different amount of text in these columns. So the answer given in those tutorials is to apply:

```
.row-container > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

on Flexbox container's direct children like in [this video](https://youtu.be/vQAvjof1oe4?si=SyJedqCA46LpCL-P), and the problem is solved.
The columns containing different amount of text are equal width now.

In my case I have similar layout, but while in first Flexbox column I have text, in second Flexbox column I only have an image, that I want to be responsive size.
And the result is that currently, the second Flexbox column is much bigger than the first column, containing only text. And I want them to be equal width.

[image]

How to make these 2 Flexbox columns the same size (width), and the image in the 2nd column must be responsive?

[Photo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ATiGbYJBt2GgoWic7)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  /* https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.php */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp */
}

:root {
  --background-col: #1B1B1B;
  /* previuosly the background was #FAF3F0 */
  --font-col: #F5F5F5;
  --transition-col: #EE578A;
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
}

* {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

html {
  margin: 1px 1px;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-col);
  /* previuosly the background was #FAF3F0 */
  color: var(--font-col);
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  padding: 0 0;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist>li,
a,
button {
  /* The > (child combinator) in .header-ulist > li is used to target only the immediate children of the <.header-ulist> element, providing more specific control over styling. */
  color: var(--font-col);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* stretch, flex-start, flex-end, center, baseline */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* flex-start, flex-end, !space-between!, center, space-evenly */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* row, row-reverse, column, column-reverse */
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist {
  list-style: none;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist>li {
  /* select .header-ulist's direct children li elements  */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header-nav-anchor>a {
  /* select .header-nav-anchor's direct children a elements  */
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.header-nav-anchor>a:hover {
  color: var(--transition-col);
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
}

.mroesler>button {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: var(--transition-col);
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
  color: var(--background-col);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease 0ms, color 400ms ease 400ms;
  /* transition-property transition-duration transition-timing-function transition-delay */
}

.mroesler>button:hover {
  background-color: var(--background-col);
  color: var(--font-col);
}

.row-container {
  display: flex;
}

.row-container>* {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="h1">Joanna<br>Kowalska<br>Resume</h1>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <ul class="header-ulist">
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="index.html">main pink</a></li>
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="index2.html">main gray1</a></li>
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="index3.html">main gray2</a></li>
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="myprojects.html">myprojects</a></li>
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="mroesler" href="https://mroesler.com/" target="_blank"><button>mroesler</button></a>
  </header>

  <div class="row-container">
    <section class="column-container">
      <h2 class="h2">Joanna Kowalska<br>Senior Accountant in<br> Captive Finance Organization<br>VFS Usługi Finansowe Sp&nbsp;z&nbsp;o.o.</h2>
      <p class="initial-paragraph">Joanna Kowalska Senior Accountant in Captive Finance Organization</p>
      <ul>
        <li>first responsibility description</li>
        <li>second responsibility description</li>
        <li>third responsibility description</li>
        <li>fourth responsibility description</li>
        <li>fifth responsibility description</li>
        <li>sixth responsibility description</li>
        <li>seventh responsibility description</li>
        <li>eighth responsibility description</li>
        <li>january 2022 - present moment</li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img-fluid40" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" alt="joanna_kowalska">
      <!-- <img src="images/wizytowka.png" alt="wizytowka" width="600"> -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="previous">My Previous Positions<br>and Professional Experience</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you specified your image width in your <img> tag as 100% ?

Comment: No I didn't. This is the index.html part with the image: 
<div class="img-container">
   <img class="img-fluid40" src="./images/asia_profile_picture.jpeg" alt="joanna_kowalska"></div>

Answer (score 1):

I've added the code from your question into the example below, but the main points are that you need to add min-width's and max-width's to your content.

If you add a min-width to both your columns, then they'll both be the same size.

If you add a max width of 100% to your image, then it won't take up more than it's containers size.

Try the below snippet yourself and see if this helps.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  /* https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.php */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp */
}

:root {
  --background-col: #1B1B1B;
  /* previuosly the background was #FAF3F0 */
  --font-col: #F5F5F5;
  --transition-col: #EE578A;
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
}

* {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

html {
  margin: 1px 1px;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-col);
  /* previuosly the background was #FAF3F0 */
  color: var(--font-col);
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  padding: 0 0;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist>li,
a,
button {
  /* The > (child combinator) in .header-ulist > li is used to target only the immediate children of the <.header-ulist> element, providing more specific control over styling. */
  color: var(--font-col);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* stretch, flex-start, flex-end, center, baseline */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* flex-start, flex-end, !space-between!, center, space-evenly */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* row, row-reverse, column, column-reverse */
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist {
  list-style: none;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}

.header-ulist>li {
  /* select .header-ulist's direct children li elements  */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header-nav-anchor>a {
  /* select .header-nav-anchor's direct children a elements  */
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.header-nav-anchor>a:hover {
  color: var(--transition-col);
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
}

.mroesler>button {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: var(--transition-col);
  /* previous color was #0088A9 */
  color: var(--background-col);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  transition: background-color 400ms ease 0ms, color 400ms ease 400ms;
  /* transition-property transition-duration transition-timing-function transition-delay */
}

.mroesler>button:hover {
  background-color: var(--background-col);
  color: var(--font-col);
}

.row-container {
  display: flex;
}

.column-container,
img-container {
  min-width: 50%;
}

.img-fluid40 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="header-nav-anchor"><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="mroesler" href="https://mroesler.com/" target="_blank"><button>mroesler</button></a>
  </header>

  <div class="row-container">
    <section class="column-container">
      <h2 class="h2">Joanna Kowalska<br>Senior Accountant in<br> Captive Finance Organization<br>VFS Usługi Finansowe Sp&nbsp;z&nbsp;o.o.</h2>
      <p class="initial-paragraph">Joanna Kowalska Senior Accountant in Captive Finance Organization</p>
      <ul>
        <li>first responsibility description</li>
        <li>second responsibility description</li>
        <li>third responsibility description</li>
        <li>fourth responsibility description</li>
        <li>fifth responsibility description</li>
        <li>sixth responsibility description</li>
        <li>seventh responsibility description</li>
        <li>eighth responsibility description</li>
        <li>january 2022 - present moment</li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img-fluid40" src="https://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg?2" alt="joanna_kowalska">
      <!-- <img src="images/wizytowka.png" alt="wizytowka" width="600"> -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="previous">My Previous Positions<br>and Professional Experience</h2>
</body>

</html>
```